# Lumen: Preciso exibir duas datas em um único campo

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Tenho que retornar um json que exibe um objeto Person que contem Outro objeto Experience. estou usando o hasMany no Model Person e retornando o Json dessa forma:

```
$person = $this->model->with('experiences')->find($id);
return response()->json($person, Response::HTTP_OK);
```

e recebo como retorno o Json:

```
{
    "name": "João",
    "last_name": "Antonio",
    "experiences": [
        {
            "date_start": "2019-02-01",
            "date_end": "2019-03-04",
            "description": "Descrição"
        }
    ]
}
```

Preciso retornar um campo "date" que contenha o campo date_start e date_end no seguinte formato:

```
{
    "name": "João",
    "last_name": "Antonio",
    "experiences": [
        {
            "date": "February 2019 - March 2019",
            "description": "Descrição"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa formata a saída direto na `SQL` da relação com o [Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries) do [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent) e na `SQL` o [date_format](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) que abre um leque de como formata saída de um data, ***exemplo***:

```
$person = $this->model
          ->with(['experiences' => function($query){
              $query->selectRaw(
                'id,
                 description,
                 concat(date_format(date_start,"%M %Y"),"-",date_format(date_end,"%M %Y")) 
                 as date'
              );
           }])
          ->find($id);
```

onde e muita observação nisso o primeiro item eu coloquei a palavra `id` mais ai é o campo que relaciona com a tabela `$person`. Exemplo se a tabela `experiences` relaciona com `person` pelo campo `person_id` é esse nome que deve ser colocado no lugar do `id` do exemplo assim, o resto fica do jeito que está.

Comment: Obrigado, deu muito certo